# how to use loader in Fragment Class in which data is coming from json?

Tags: android

```
     public class MyFragment extends Fragment {
int mCurrentPage;
Context c;
GridView mListView;
String id, cat;
String strUrl;
TextView tvtitle;
TextView tv_id, tv_rating, tv_url;
public static String img_url, img_rating, img_id, img_name;
private ImageLoader imageLoader;
private DisplayImageOptions options;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Bundle data = getArguments();
    mCurrentPage = data.getInt("current_page", 0);
    imageLoader=ImageLoader.getInstance();

    options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
    .showImageOnLoading(R.drawable.empty_photo)
    .showImageForEmptyUri(R.drawable.empty_photo)
    .showImageOnFail(R.drawable.empty_photo)
    .cacheInMemory(true)
    .cacheOnDisc(true)
    .displayer(new RoundedBitmapDisplayer(20))
    .build();
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = null;
    DownloadTask downloadTask = new DownloadTask();
    v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.starters, container, false);
    tv_id = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv_starter_hide_id);
    tv_rating = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv_starter_hide_ratinf);
    tv_url = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tv_starter_hide_url);
    cat = Category.Main_Cat;
    Log.i("Logcat Cat1", cat);
    switch (mCurrentPage) {
    case 1:
        Log.v("MyFragment Heap", "Max Mem in MB:"
                + (Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory() / 1024 / 1024));
        // strUrl =
        // "http://vaibhavtech.com/work/android/get_json.php?cat="+cat+"&subcat=1";
        strUrl = " http://vaibhavtech.com/work/android/movie_list.php?category=BollyWood%20&sub_category=top";
        downloadTask.execute(strUrl);
        mListView = (GridView) v.findViewById(R.id.lv_countries);
        mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                    int arg2, long arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent i = new Intent(getActivity().getBaseContext(),
                        Starter_info.class);
                img_id = ((TextView) arg1
                        .findViewById(R.id.tv_starter_hide_id)).getText()
                        .toString();
                img_rating = ((TextView) arg1
                        .findViewById(R.id.tv_starter_hide_ratinf))
                        .getText().toString();
                img_url = ((TextView) arg1
                        .findViewById(R.id.tv_starter_hide_url)).getText()
                        .toString();
                img_name = ((TextView) arg1
                        .findViewById(R.id.tv_starter_hide_imagename))
                        .getText().toString();
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
        break;
    case 2:
        // strUrl =
        // "http://vaibhavtech.com/work/android/get_json.php?cat="+cat+"&subcat=1";
        strUrl = " http://vaibhavtech.com/work/android/movie_list.php?category=BollyWood%20&sub_category=top";
        downloadTask.execute(strUrl);
        Log.v("Splash Heap", "Max Mem in MB:"
                + (Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory() / 1024 / 1024));
        mListView = (GridView) v.findViewById(R.id.lv_countries);
        mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                    int arg2, long arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent i = new Intent(getActivity().getBaseContext(),
                        Starter_info.class);
                img_id = ((TextView) arg1
                        .findViewById(R.id.tv_starter_hide_id)).getText()
                        .toString();
                img_rating = ((TextView) arg1
                        .findViewById(R.id.tv_starter_hide_ratinf))
                        .getText().toString();
                img_url = ((TextView) arg1
                        .findViewById(R.id.tv_starter_hide_url)).getText()
                        .toString();
                img_name = ((TextView) arg1
                        .findViewById(R.id.tv_starter_hide_imagename))
                        .getText().toString();
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
        break;
    default:
        Log.i("Cat IS", Category.Main_Cat);
        // strUrl =
        // "http://vaibhavtech.com/work/android/get_json.php?cat="+cat+"&subcat=1";
        strUrl = " http://vaibhavtech.com/work/android/movie_list.php?category=BollyWood%20&sub_category=top";
        downloadTask.execute(strUrl);
        Log.v("Splash Heap", "Max Mem in MB:"
                + (Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory() / 1024 / 1024));
        mListView = (GridView) v.findViewById(R.id.lv_countries);
        mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                    int arg2, long arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent i = new Intent(getActivity().getBaseContext(),
                        Starter_info.class);
                img_id = ((TextView) arg1
                        .findViewById(R.id.tv_starter_hide_id)).getText()
                        .toString();
                img_rating = ((TextView) arg1
                        .findViewById(R.id.tv_starter_hide_ratinf))
                        .getText().toString();
                img_url = ((TextView) arg1
                        .findViewById(R.id.tv_starter_hide_url)).getText()
                        .toString();
                img_name = ((TextView) arg1
                        .findViewById(R.id.tv_starter_hide_imagename))
                        .getText().toString();
                startActivity(i);

            }
        });
        break;
    }
    return v;
}

private String downloadUrl(String strUrl) throws IOException {
    String data = "";
    InputStream iStream = null;
    try {
        URL url = new URL(strUrl);
        // Creating an http connection to communicate with url
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url
                .openConnection();
        // Connecting to url
        urlConnection.connect();
        // Reading data from url
        iStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                iStream));
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        String line = "";
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line);
        }
        data = sb.toString();
        br.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("Exception while downloading url", e.toString());
    } finally {
        iStream.close();
    }

    return data;
}

private class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {
    String data = null;

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... url) {
        try {
            data = downloadUrl(url[0]);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("Background Task", e.toString());
        }
        return data;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        ListViewLoaderTask listViewLoaderTask = new ListViewLoaderTask();
        listViewLoaderTask.execute(result);
    }

}

private class ListViewLoaderTask extends
        AsyncTask<String, Void, List<HashMap<String, Object>>> {
    JSONObject jObject;
    @Override
    protected List<HashMap<String, Object>> doInBackground(String... strJson) {
        try {
            jObject = new JSONObject(strJson[0]);
            StarterParser countryJsonParser = new StarterParser();
            countryJsonParser.parse(jObject);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("JSON Exception1", e.toString());
        }
        StarterParser countryJsonParser = new StarterParser();
        List<HashMap<String, Object>> countries=null;
        try {
            // Getting the parsed data as a List construct
            countries = countryJsonParser.parse(jObject);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("Exception", e.toString());
        }
        return countries;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<HashMap<String, Object>> countries) {
        mListView.setAdapter(new WallPaperAdapter(countries));
    }
}
public class WallPaperAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private LayoutInflater mInflater = null;
    private List<HashMap<String, Object>> countries = null;
    public WallPaperAdapter(List<HashMap<String, Object>> countries) {
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity());
        this.countries=countries;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return countries.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.lv_layout,
                    null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();

            holder.txtId = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.tv_starter_hide_id);
            holder.txtDuration = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.tv_starter_hide_ratinf);
            holder.txtTitle= (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.tv_starter_hide_imagename);
            holder.txtYear = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.tv_starter_hide_url);
            holder.imgPoster= (ImageView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.iv_flag);
            convertView.setTag(holder);

        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        try {
            holder.txtId.setText(countries.get(position)
                            .get("id").toString());
            holder.txtDuration.setText(countries.get(position)
                    .get("duration").toString());
            holder.txtTitle.setText(countries.get(position)
                    .get("title").toString());
            holder.txtYear.setText(countries.get(position)
                    .get("year").toString());
            Log.v("Image Loader URL",countries.get(position)
                    .get("flag_path").toString());
            imageLoader.displayImage(countries.get(position)
                            .get("flag_path").toString(),holder.imgPoster,options);

        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        return convertView;
    }

    class ViewHolder {

        public TextView txtId;
        public TextView txtDuration;
        public TextView txtTitle;
        public TextView txtYear;
        public ImageView imgPoster;

    }
}

  }
```

i am using a gridview in which i want a loader which show sloding process till when image sare loading in my gridview.my image sare coming from json..,what i do for this..,pleas egive me any suggetion for this,thankyou.

Comment: Place a progress bar above the image and in the adapter class if u use imageloader there exists one load listener for loading images. so while onLoadingStarted make the image invisible and progress bar visible and onLoading completed make the image visible and progress bar invisible.

Answer (score 0):

Add this code in your  AsyncTask:

```
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // Showing progress dialog before sending http request
        ProgressDialog pDialog = new ProgressDialog(your_activity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Please wait..");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();
    }
```

And for post execute:

```
protected void onPostExecute(Void unused) {
            // closing progress dialog
            pDialog.dismiss();
        }
```

This will might help you....